# does input validation fits into detailed use case description?

Tags: use-case

Suppose I am developing a web application. Now, I have a form where user need to fill in the form where the form contains both client side and server side validation. Does this validation fits into detail use case description? if not, where should it generally fit into a system document report?

Note: Server side validation does not necessary fits to database schema 
Example: database column can contain maximum 10 characters but validation allow user enter 6 characters only

Comment: This question appears to be [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, a use case's description contains a main success scenario that describe how a goal is achieved, and it breaks down into action steps. Validation is one kind of an action step.

Source: Alistair Cockburn, Writing Effective Use Cases, pp. 1,3,87,95

However, use cases should only say that the validation happens. Details like max. allowed characters will typically not be pointed out, because the point of use cases is to show what a system does for whom.

Validation details can for example become acceptance criteria of a user story in an agile context, or part of requirements in the traditional context.